# MySQL same query result in multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize following query.

```
SELECT t3.*, 
        (SELECT SUM(t4.col_sum)
            FROM (...) t4
            WHERE t4.timestamp BETWEEN CONCAT(SUBSTR(t3.timestamp, 1, 11), "00:00:00") AND t3.timestamp)
        AS cum_sum
FROM (...) t3
```

Where (...) is a container for long query. It results 2 columns: timestamp and col_sum. I want to add third column to it by writing a query. That third column is a cumulative sum of col_sum.

The problem is I am putting same big query in two places (...)

Is there a way I can obtain a result and use the result in those two/multiple places (...)?

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use a temporary table.

Probably a more efficient method is to use variables to calculate a cumulative sum.  It would be something like:

```
  select t.*,
         (@c := if(@t = left(t.timestamp, 11), @c + t.col_sum,
                   if(@t := left(t.timestamp, 11), 0, 0)
                  )
         ) as cumesum
  from (. . .) t cross join
       (select @t := '', @c := 0) vars
  order by t.timestamp;
```

The above query orders the rows by `timestamp`.  The variable `@t` keeps track of the first 11 characters in the timestamp -- as I read your logic, you want to do the cumulative sum only within a group where this is constant.

The variable `@c` keeps track of the cumulative sum, resetting to zero when a new "first 11 characters" are encountered.  The logic looks a bit complicated, but it is best to put all variable assignments in a single expression, because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.

Comment: it works, can you add explanation as how it works? I have never used mysql variables before. I am looking into this now.